# Launching Pry on the command line errors out

Tags: ruby, rvm, pry

So this is what i get when I launch the `pry` command at my Zsh.
I've tried reinstalling using

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
rvm repair all
```

and even

```
rvm reinstall all --force
```

At a loss as to how to get rid of this.

```
/Users/tsax/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/pry-debugger-0.2.1/lib/pry- debugger/processor.rb:98: warning: don't put space before argument parentheses 
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_iseq_translate_threaded_code
  Referenced from: /Users/tsax/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/debugger-1.2.4/lib/ruby_debug.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

 dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_iseq_translate_threaded_code
  Referenced from: /Users/tsax/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/debugger- 1.2.4/lib/ruby_debug.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

[1]    67115 trace trap  pry
```

Comment: have you tried: `rvm use 1.9.3 --install`?

Comment: Yes, this is the message I get:
Using /Users/[user]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385

Comment: Do you have ruby-debug19 in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

i hade same problem with vim-ruby-debugger, it looks like you don't have correct libxml2 in you system, try

```
 $ brew install libxml2
```

drop your gemset and create it again